# How to make an integer from it's numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, c++14

I have a number, which I have to write backward. I already separated it's digits in an array, but how can I make the new number from this array?

Comment: Plz show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store digits in an array to reverse digits of number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int input;
    cin>>input;
    int reverse = 0;
    while(input)
    {
        reverse *= 10;
        reverse += input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }
    cout << reverse << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a good cut. You can simplify this further because No one's asked that you store the reverse: `int main()
{
    int input;
    cin>>input;
    while(input)
    {
        cout << input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @user4581301 The limitation with your code is that it doesn't store the reversed number in any variable. It only prints on the screen.

Comment: As per the Asker's question: "which I have to write backwards" No one said anything about storing it. If they come back later and require that it be stored, you have them fill out an engineering change order or bill them extra, depending on the terms of your employment.

Comment: @user4581301 He also mentioned `make the new number`.
Let's end this saying that we both interpreted differently. PEACE

Comment: Works for me. You've had my upvote for something like 15 minutes anyway.